# Combining generic type parameters with interfaces in Java

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

As with many inheritance problems, I find it hard to explain what I want to do. But a quick (but peculiar) example should do the trick:

```
public interface Shell{


    public double getSize();

}

public class TortoiseShell implements Shell{
     ...
     public double getSize(){...} //implementing interface method
     ...
     public Tortoise getTortoise(){...} //new method
     ...
}

public class ShellViewer<S extends Shell>{

     S shell;

     public ShellViewer(S shell){
         this.shell = shell;
         ...
     }

}

public class TortoiseShellViewer<T extends TortoiseShell> extends ShellViewer{

    public TortoiseShellViewer(T tShell){
         super(tShell); //no problems here...
    }

    private void removeTortoise(){
        Tortoise t = tShell.getTortoise(); //ERROR: compiler can not find method in "Shell"
        ...
    }
}
```

The compiler does not recognise that I want to use a specific implementation of Shell for `getTortoise()`. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Mostly you've gone wrong by assuming that Java generics are the same as C++'s templates.

Comment: Might want to remove the huge red herring of `getTortoise` returning a double in one place and a `Tortoise` elsewhere.

Comment: Woops. Thanks! Edited for future reference

Comment: Another thing that'd be helpful would be to include all relevant information in the code you're showing... the declaration of the field `tShell` in `ShellViewer` is important here but missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on what you've given here, the problem is that:

```
public class TortoiseShellViewer<T extends TortoiseShell> extends ShellViewer
```

does not specify `ShellViewer` (which is generic) correctly. It should be:

```
public class TortoiseShellViewer<T extends TortoiseShell> extends ShellViewer<T>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. My understanding in generics just increased 10-fold.

Answer (score 4):

You want this:

```
public class TortoiseShellViewer<T extends ToroiseShell> extends ShellViewer<T>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is tShell in removeTortoise? Is it an instance of type Shell that is in the base class ShellViewer?

Comment: It should be an instance of TortoiseShell. Or, an instance of generic type T, which extends TotoiseShell. Sorry if it's a bit confsuing to read. My actual code was too bogged down in its own application to use here...